# GCP K8s No Scale Up Events Log Based Metrics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

I am trying to create a custom alert from a log-based metric in GCP for a K8s node pool no.scale.up event.
I am using the current query:

```
resource.labels.project_id="my_project"
resource.labels.location="my_zone"
resource.labels.cluster_name="my_cluster"
logName="projects/my_project/logs/container.googleapis.com%2Fcluster-autoscaler-visibility"
jsonPayload.noDecisionStatus.noScaleUp.reason.messageId="no.scale.up.in.backoff" OR
jsonPayload.noDecisionStatus.noScaleUp.napFailureReason.messageId="no.scale.up.nap.disabled" OR
jsonPayload.noDecisionStatus.noScaleUp.napFailureReason.messageId="no.scale.up.nap.no.locations.available" OR
jsonPayload.noDecisionStatus.noScaleUp.skippedMigs[].reason.messageId="no.scale.up.mig.skipped" OR
jsonPayload.noDecisionStatus.noScaleUp.unhandledPodGroups[].rejectedMigs[].reason.messageId="no.scale.up.mig.failing.predicate" OR
jsonPayload.noDecisionStatus.noScaleUp.unhandledPodGroups[].napFailureReasons[].reason.messageId="no.scale.up.nap.pod.gpu.no.limit.defined" OR
jsonPayload.noDecisionStatus.noScaleUp.unhandledPodGroups[].napFailureReasons[].reason.messageId="no.scale.up.nap.pod.gpu.type.not.supported" OR
jsonPayload.noDecisionStatus.noScaleUp.unhandledPodGroups[].napFailureReasons[].reason.messageId="no.scale.up.nap.pod.gpu.other.error" OR
jsonPayload.noDecisionStatus.noScaleUp.unhandledPodGroups[].napFailureReasons[].reason.messageId="no.scale.up.nap.pod.zonal.resources.exceeded" OR
jsonPayload.noDecisionStatus.noScaleUp.unhandledPodGroups[].napFailureReasons[].reason.messageId="no.scale.up.nap.pod.zonal.failing.predicates"
```

Its a pretty exhaustive query that does not look right to me.
This query works and it does extract data from the logs.

Reading the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler-visibility#eventresult-event
it talks about eventResult's but I cannot figure out how to get to these?
They do not appear to be in the cluster-autoscaler-visibility log.

Are the eventResults in this log: logName="projects/my_project/logs/events"?
(If so I could not find them with any query)
I have tried a query:

```
resource.type="k8s_cluster"
resource.labels.project_id="my_project"
resource.labels.location="my_zone"
resource.labels.cluster_name="my_cluster"
logName="projects/my_project/logs/events"
jsonPayload.resultInfo.results[].errorMsg = "scale.down.error.failed.to.mark.to.be.deleted" OR
jsonPayload.resultInfo.results[].errorMsg = "scale.down.error.failed.to.evict.pods" OR
jsonPayload.resultInfo.results[].errorMsg = "scale.down.error.failed.to.delete.node.min.size.reached" OR
jsonPayload.resultInfo.results[].errorMsg = "scale.up.error.out.of.resources" OR
jsonPayload.resultInfo.results[].errorMsg = "scale.up.error.quota.exceeded" OR
jsonPayload.resultInfo.results[].errorMsg = "scale.up.error.waiting.for.instances.timeout"
```

This does not produce anything useful even though I have no.scale.down and no.scale.up events searchable in the log explorer.

Comment: I don't understand why using the logName part, I guess you can skip it . Have you tried with ```noScaleUp``` and ```noScaleDown``` events as seen in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler-visibility#cluster-not-scalingup)? It may also simplify the query the use of [EventResult](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler-visibility#eventresult-event) event, because ```An empty error message indicates the event completed successfully.```